# Running `grunt serve` ignores sass import

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, jekyll, yeoman, compass-sass

**Background information:**

I am currently exploring using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) to generate a Jekyll site using [generator-jekyllrb](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb). I am using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) to help pull everything together. The documentation for [generator-jekyllrb](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) contains more information about my base setup.

**The problem**

Currently, I am trying to use Bootstrap, which I've installed using Bower. My `main.scss` file looks like the following:

```
@import 'bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
@import 'custom/reset';
```

When I run `grunt build`, everything works correctly -- Grunt compiles both the bootstrap files and my own custom reset/sass file.

However, when I run `grunt serve`, Grunt initially seems to completely ignore the bootstrap files. It successfully compiles my custom styles, but ignores bootstrap altogether.

**What I've tried**

I did manage to find a workaround: if I make any change to `main.scss` (even something as minor as adding a space), Grunt will correctly compile both bootstrap and my styles. However, this is very annoying, and I would prefer to just have everything working correctly from the start.

I've tried deleting the `.jekyll`, `.sass-cache`, `.tmp`, and `dist` folders in case there's some cache that's in a broken state, but doing so had no effect.

At this point, I suspect that the problem is with my `Gruntfile.js` file. The tasks Grunt performs when serving vs building are fairly different, so I'm wondering if the issue is caused by something I have for one task but not the other.

Unfortunately, I've never used either Yeoman or Grunt before, so I don't seem to be able to identify exactly what the problem is or how to fix it.

**My code**

Here's my gruntfile:

```
// Generated on 2014-07-08 using generator-jekyllrb 1.2.1
'use strict';

// Directory reference:
//   css: _assets/css
//   compass: _assets/scss
//   javascript: _assets/javascript
//   images: _assets/media
//   fonts: _assets/fonts

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // Show elapsed time after tasks run
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  // Load all Grunt tasks
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    // Configurable paths
    yeoman: {
      app: 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    watch: {
      compass: {
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/scss/**/*.{scss,sass}',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer:server']
      },
      autoprefixer: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/css/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['copy:stageCss', 'autoprefixer:server']
      },
      jekyll: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.{html,yml,md,mkd,markdown}',
          '!<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components/**/*'
        ],
        tasks: ['jekyll:server']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '.jekyll/**/*.html',
          '.tmp/_assets/css/**/*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/<%= js %>/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/media/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg,webp}'
        ]
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        livereload: 35729,
        // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '.jekyll',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '.jekyll',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            // Running Jekyll also cleans the target directory.  Exclude any
            // non-standard `keep_files` here (e.g., the generated files
            // directory from Jekyll Picture Tag).
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: [
        '.tmp',
        '.jekyll'
      ]
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        // If you're using global Sass gems, require them here.
        // require: ['singularity', 'jacket'],
        bundleExec: true,
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/scss',
        cssDir: '.tmp/_assets/css',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/media',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/javascript',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components',
        relativeAssets: false,
        httpImagesPath: '/_assets/media',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/_assets/media/generated',
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        raw: 'extensions_dir = "<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components"\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/media/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true,
          generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/_assets/media/generated'
        }
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css',
          src: '**/*.css',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css'
        }]
      },
      server: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/_assets/css',
          src: '**/*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/_assets/css'
        }]
      }
    },
    jekyll: {
      options: {
        bundleExec: true,
        config: '_config.yml,_config.build.yml',
        src: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          config: '_config.yml',
          dest: '.jekyll'
        }
      },
      check: {
        options: {
          doctor: true
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      },
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css/**/*.css']
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.html',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    // Usemin adds files to concat
    concat: {},
    // Usemin adds files to uglify
    uglify: {},
    // Usemin adds files to cssmin
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          check: 'gzip'
        }
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          progressive: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: [
              // Jekyll processes and moves HTML and text files.
              // Usemin moves CSS and javascript inside of Usemin blocks.
              // Copy moves asset files and directories.
              '_assets/media/**/*',
              '_assets/fonts/**/*',
              // Like Jekyll, exclude files & folders prefixed with an underscore.
              '!**/_*{,/**}',
              // Explicitly add any files your site needs for distribution here.
              //'_bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
              //'favicon.ico',
              //'apple-touch*.png'
            ],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          },
          {
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: [
              '_bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/**/*'
            ],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css/bootstrap'
          }
        ]
      },
      // Copy CSS into .tmp directory for Autoprefixer processing
      stageCss: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/css',
            src: '**/*.css',
            dest: '.tmp/_assets/css'
          },
          {
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: [
              '_bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/**/*'
            ],
            dest: '.tmp/_assets/css/bootstrap'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    filerev: {
      options: {
        length: 4
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/javascript/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css/**/*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/media/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg,webp}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/fonts/**/*.{eot*,otf,svg,ttf,woff}'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },
    buildcontrol: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          remote: '../',
          branch: 'gh-pages',
          commit: true,
          push: true
        }
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/javascript/**/*.js',
        'test/spec/**/*.js'
      ]
    },
    csslint: {
      options: {
        csslintrc: '.csslintrc'
      },
      check: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/css/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/scss/**/*.scss'
        ]
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server',
        'copy:stageCss',
        'jekyll:server'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'copy:dist'
      ]
    }
  });

  // Define Tasks
  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  // No real tests yet. Add your own.
  grunt.registerTask('test', [
  //   'clean:server',
  //   'concurrent:test',
  //   'connect:test'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('check', [
    'clean:server',
    'jekyll:check',
    'compass:server',
    'jshint:all',
    'csslint:check'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean',
    // Jekyll cleans files from the target directory, so must run first
    'jekyll:dist',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'autoprefixer:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
    ]);

  grunt.registerTask('deploy', [
    'check',
    'test',
    'build',
    'buildcontrol'
    ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'check',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

If you want to play with the entire codebase, you can clone the [github repo](https://github.com/Michael0x2a/uwfig):

```
git clone https://github.com/Michael0x2a/uwfig.git
cd uwfig
bundle install
bower install
npm install
```

You can then reproduce the behavior by running:

```
grunt serve
```

Grunt should be serving the default Jekyll page on `localhost:9000`. I've added two buttons to the page, both using styles from Bootstrap. If Bootstrap were working the left button would be colored blue, while the right button would have a star glyphicon inside. Currently, the bootstrap styles are not being applied and the buttons are plain.

I'm currently using Windows 8.1, Ruby version 1.9.3p545, Node.js version 0.10.26, grunt version 0.4.5, and grunt-cli version 0.1.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've managed to fix my issue, though I'm not entirely sure how.

Here are the major changes I've made:

1. Modified my project and Gruntfile to use wiredep, which I essentially copied from the one created by generator-angular
2. Modified my `main.css` file to look like the following:

   ```
   $icon-font-path: "/_bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

   // bower:scss
   @import "../../_bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss";
   // endbower 

   @import 'custom/reset';
   ```
3. Called the `copy:dist` task instead of `copy:stageCss` when serving files.

I'm not entirely sure exactly what fixed it -- all I know for certain is that #3 is definitely a factor, but is also definitely not the *only* factor. Nothing was working until I applied change #3, but applying #3 in isolation on a fresh repo causes no change.

You can see the full diff here:

https://github.com/Michael0x2a/uwfig/commit/8d037a619ff09e9d3f5eae4de85e06ea2e69b24c

Here's my final Gruntfile, for reference:

```
// Generated on 2014-07-08 using generator-jekyllrb 1.2.1
'use strict';

// Directory reference:
//   css: _assets/css
//   compass: _assets/scss
//   javascript: _assets/javascript
//   images: _assets/media
//   fonts: _assets/fonts

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // Show elapsed time after tasks run
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  // Load all Grunt tasks
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    // Configurable paths
    yeoman: {
      app: 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      compass: {
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/scss/**/*.{scss,sass}',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer:server']
      },
      autoprefixer: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/css/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['copy:stageCss', 'autoprefixer:server']
      },
      jekyll: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.{html,yml,md,mkd,markdown}',
          '!<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components/**/*'
        ],
        tasks: ['jekyll:server']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '.jekyll/**/*.html',
          '.tmp/_assets/css/**/*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/<%= js %>/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/media/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg,webp}'
        ]
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        livereload: 35729,
        // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '.jekyll',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '.jekyll',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            // Running Jekyll also cleans the target directory.  Exclude any
            // non-standard `keep_files` here (e.g., the generated files
            // directory from Jekyll Picture Tag).
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: [
        '.tmp',
        '.jekyll'
      ]
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        // If you're using global Sass gems, require them here.
        // require: ['singularity', 'jacket'],
        bundleExec: true,
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/scss',
        cssDir: '.tmp/_assets/css',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/media',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/javascript',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components/',
        relativeAssets: false,
        httpImagesPath: '/_assets/media',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/_assets/media/generated',
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        raw: 'extensions_dir = "<%= yeoman.app %>/_bower_components"\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/media/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true,
          generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/_assets/media/generated'
        }
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css',
          src: '**/*.css',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css'
        }]
      },
      server: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/_assets/css',
          src: '**/*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/_assets/css'
        }]
      }
    },
    wiredep: {
      options: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      },
      app: {
        src: ['<% yeoman.app%>/_layouts/*.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app%>/_assets/scss/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
      }
    },
    jekyll: {
      options: {
        bundleExec: true,
        config: '_config.yml,_config.build.yml',
        src: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          config: '_config.yml',
          dest: '.jekyll'
        }
      },
      check: {
        options: {
          doctor: true
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      },
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css/**/*.css']
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.html',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    // Usemin adds files to concat
    concat: {},
    // Usemin adds files to uglify
    uglify: {},
    // Usemin adds files to cssmin
    cssmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          check: 'gzip'
        }
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          progressive: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: [
              // Jekyll processes and moves HTML and text files.
              // Usemin moves CSS and javascript inside of Usemin blocks.
              // Copy moves asset files and directories.
              '_assets/media/**/*',
              '_assets/fonts/**/*',
              // Like Jekyll, exclude files & folders prefixed with an underscore.
              '!**/_*{,/**}',
              // Explicitly add any files your site needs for distribution here.
              //'_bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
              //'favicon.ico',
              //'apple-touch*.png'
            ],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          },
          {
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: [
              '_bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/**/*'
            ],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css/bootstrap'
          }
        ]
      },
      server: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: [
              // Jekyll processes and moves HTML and text files.
              // Usemin moves CSS and javascript inside of Usemin blocks.
              // Copy moves asset files and directories.
              '_assets/media/**/*',
              '_assets/fonts/**/*',
              // Like Jekyll, exclude files & folders prefixed with an underscore.
              '!**/_*{,/**}',
              // Explicitly add any files your site needs for distribution here.
              //'_bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
              //'favicon.ico',
              //'apple-touch*.png'
            ],
            dest: '.tmp'
          },
          {
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: [
              '_bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/**/*'
            ],
            dest: '.tmp/_assets/css/bootstrap'
          }
        ]
      },
      // Copy CSS into .tmp directory for Autoprefixer processing
      stageCss: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/css',
            src: '**/*.css',
            dest: '.tmp/_assets/css'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    filerev: {
      options: {
        length: 4
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/javascript/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/css/**/*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/media/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg,webp}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/_assets/fonts/**/*.{eot*,otf,svg,ttf,woff}'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },
    buildcontrol: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          remote: '../',
          branch: 'gh-pages',
          commit: true,
          push: true
        }
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/javascript/**/*.js',
        'test/spec/**/*.js'
      ]
    },
    csslint: {
      options: {
        csslintrc: '.csslintrc'
      },
      check: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/css/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/_assets/scss/**/*.scss'
        ]
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server',
        'copy:server',
        'jekyll:server'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'copy:dist'
      ]
    }
  });

  // Define Tasks
  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  // No real tests yet. Add your own.
  grunt.registerTask('test', [
  //   'clean:server',
  //   'concurrent:test',
  //   'connect:test'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('check', [
    'clean:server',
    'jekyll:check',
    'compass:server',
    'jshint:all',
    'csslint:check'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean',
    // Jekyll cleans files from the target directory, so must run first
    'jekyll:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'autoprefixer:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
    ]);

  grunt.registerTask('deploy', [
    'check',
    'test',
    'build',
    'buildcontrol'
    ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'check',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Jekyll config.yml file, did you set :

```
sass:
    sass_dir: root-path-of-your-imported-files-folder
```

If you have this structure

```
-root/
  -css/
    -main.scss
    -bootstrap-sass-official/
        -base.scss
        -...
    -custom/
        -reset.scss
        -...
```

Your **sass_dir** is **css/**